# drawing a 100x100 persistent rectangle over the current user screen in win10 app

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I am very new to the win10 dev, and I am trying to create a win10 app which will draw a rectangle as a border of the current user screen. The rectangle has to be persistent and it has to be floating all the times. This rectangle cannot be attached to any application window, it has to be system wide. I have followed few leads but did not find any success in finding a solution. Any lead will be great. Thanks.

Below were my trials.

1. Getting foremost window using GetForegroundWindow() and draw rectangle using GDI API, but I need a system wide drawing.
2. ```
       IntPtr desktopPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
       Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(desktopPtr);

       SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
       g.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));

       g.Dispose();
       ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, desktopPtr);
   ```
3. UPDATED CODE :

   ```
   m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, L"DemoApp", L"Demo App", 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, HINST_THISCOMPONENT, this );

   const int totalWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
   const int totalHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

   HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
   HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);

   int cx = totalWidth;
   int cy = totalHeight;
   RECT rc = { 0, 0, cx, cy };
   BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
   bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
   bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = cx;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = cy;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
   RGBQUAD *prgbBits;

   //// Create memory bitmap
   HBITMAP hBmp = CreateDIBSection(hdcScreen, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &reinterpret_cast<void*&>(prgbBits), NULL, 0);

   HBITMAP hBmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDC, hBmp);
   //// Draw image to memory bitmap (currently selected in memory DC)

   //I WANT TO USE THIS TO INCREASE THE THICKNESS OF THE BORDER, BUT IT IS NOT WORKING
   HPEN hOldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hDC, CreatePen(PS_DOT, 20, RGB(255, 0, 0)));

   // Draw a simple picture
   RECT rc2 = { 0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight };
   FrameRect(hDC, &rc2, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0)));

   BLENDFUNCTION blend = { 0 };
   blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
   blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
   blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
   POINT ptLocation = { 0, 0 };
   SIZE szWnd = { cx, cy };
   POINT ptSrc = { 0, 0 };
   BOOL status1 = UpdateLayeredWindow(m_hwnd, hdcScreen, &ptLocation, &szWnd, hDC, &ptSrc, 0, &blend, ULW_ALPHA);

   BOOL status = SetWindowPos(m_hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

   hr = m_hwnd ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
       ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
       UpdateWindow(m_hwnd);
   }

   SelectObject(hDC, hOldPen);
   SelectObject(hDC, hBmpOld);
   DeleteObject(hBmp);
   DeleteObject(hOldPen);
   DeleteDC(hDC);
   ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
   ```

So far 3rd option is looking okay, but I have having two issues with above code, 1. I cannot increase the thickness of the FillRect border, 2. The border looks very dull, looks like it is having bit of transparency.

Comment: Create a top-level layered window and use [UpdateLayeredWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow) to make part of it transparent.

Comment: Is there a way to draw with out creating an extra window? I heard there is a DXGI API for this purpose.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Is there a way to get a window handle from HMONITOR, so that i can directly draw on it?

Comment: Why don't you want to create a window? It will be the easiest way to achieve your result.

Comment: A `HMONITOR` identifies a monitor. Monitors can have more than one window on them. Drawing over other apps Windows is a) rude and b) unreliable. Creating your own window is really the only way to do this.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking the same, and wanted to get clarify, I am trying the method you mentioned and it works good, expect that the border is not clear, looks like it is taking transparency from UpdateLayeredWindow, any ideas? I will update the code in some time

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I have updated the code please check

Comment: @TheNextman FYI

Comment: GDI doesn't support the alpha channel. You need to build the frame image yourself (or use gdiplus or some library that does support the alpha channel). Alternatively, don't use per-pixel alpha and use color keying instead (it seems like that's all you'd need anyway).